# How to specify the catalina container in the cmd mvn cargo:stop

Tags: maven-3, cargo-maven2-plugin

How to specify the catalina container in the cmd mvn cargo:stop :

Because whene i use it, the plugin look  for the container in the default folder of Tomcat :

AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\installs\apache-tomcat-8.0.20.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please share your maven configuration?

From your description I think you need to set container home and possibly also configuration home.

Container home should reference to installation directory of your Tomcat installation. It is set by element <home> in <container> element.

If you use existing configuration then you should also set configuration home. It is set by element <home> in <configuration> element.

You may see examples in [Cargo documentation](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Starting+and+stopping+a+container.html#Startingandstoppingacontainer-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Karel,

The default Container is in the project's target,
otherwise, if we want to use our container , we set `<home>` properties; 
in my case I do this :

```
<home>${project.basedir}/target/tomcat8x</home>
```